# Should I optimize my code myself or let the compiler/gcc to do it

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I am writing a c code and I would like to know if making simple operation like multiplication more CPU friendly makes any difference and the code faster. For example, replacing this line of code:

```
 y = x * 15;
```

with

```
 y = x << 4;
 y -= x;
```

Does the compiler already do that? Should I use the `-O2` option in order to make it happen?

Comment: You don't really know. I would guess no, it wouldn't optimize this, but I could be wrong. Just write your code, profile it, and optimize the parts that are really slowing you down. Premature optimization causes a ton of problems.

Comment: Turns out that, yes, gcc 6.3 optimizes this (if you pass -O2): https://godbolt.org/g/7ax85U

Comment: Always: **first** write code that works and write tests to test your code (and it's performance) **afterwards** optimize. This promises that your code still performs correctly AND that your optimizations actually improve performance.

Comment: in general 1) write code that is easy for a human to read/understand 2)  optimization is most useful in the logic of the algorithm, not in spot optimizations like your suggested code

Comment: @user3629249 your #1 point is very good: high level languages are meant to do exactly that - to write easily understandable code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two parts to the answer:

1. No, unless you are writing a very specialized function (e.g. a signal processing function that must execute in 20 clocks) you should not optimize; leave that to the compiler. In general your job is to write readable code, and the compiler will (to it's capability optimize it). Note that the optimization will be different for different processors as their hardware (computational capability) can be very different. For example a shift by N instruction (like that in your code) may take N clocks on a processor with a regular shifter, but it will take a single clock (or less) on processors with a hardware barrel shifter.
2. Yes, most modern optimizing compilers will optimize (for example replace multiplication by shifting where appropriate) without explicit optimization options.

Summarized, optimize only in rare situations when you already know that the compiler didn't do a good job, it is a problem that must be addressed, you know well how to do better than the compiler, and the resulting increased maintenance cost is worth it.

Answer (score 3):

Optimizing code by hand is almost always an exercise in futility these days, especially in higher level languages.  While C is almost assembly, modern compilers have a lot more tricks built into them than most people are aware of.

In addition, unless the code you're optimizing is going to be used ***a lot***, i.e., millions of times in close succession, the work of optimizing the code will cost more time than the savings you achieve.

With that said, the only way to see if your code is measurably faster would be to test it:  Put each version in a tight loop and execute it a million (or more) times, and see if there's a noticeable difference.

Note that your optimization is for a *specific* multiplier - any other operand you use it for is going to yield different results.  Because it can't be generalized, there's little likelyhood *this* optimization will be done by any compiler in all cases - and just looking at the code and not knowing what processor architecture it will be run on, I can't say whether it would be faster or not.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is this answer inaccurate or misleading?